What is the function of the 'await' keywords when no asyncio.gather(), asyncio.create_task(), etc. is (visibly) used?
I am trying to create a RabbitMQ client based on aio-pika, as I need to handle messages asynchronously. This is the quick start code for asynchronous message handling: (see original code on the aio-pika site)
import asyncio
import aio_pika

async def process_message(
    message: aio_pika.abc.AbstractIncomingMessage,
) -> None:
    async with message.process():
        print(message.body)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main() -> None:
    connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(
        "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/",
    )

    queue_name = "test_queue"

    # Creating channel
    channel = await connection.channel()

    # Maximum message count which will be processing at the same time.
    await channel.set_qos(prefetch_count=100)

    # Declaring queue
    queue = await channel.declare_queue(queue_name, auto_delete=True)

    await queue.consume(process_message)

    try:
        # Wait until terminate
        await asyncio.Future()
    finally:
        await connection.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

What I am not understanding is the use of async/await in this context. I found this tutorial that taught me of the use cases of these asyncio keywords. When I compare the information from this tutorial with the aio-pika code, however, it looks to me like the aio-pika code uses the chaining coroutines design pattern.
From the code in the tutorial, and things I tried out myself, it looks like these methods start and finish before going to the next one, making the program functionally synchronous. In this StackOverflow thread, someone asked a similar question. They asked if there is a reason to use asyncio without using methods that create a concurrent program, such as gather() and create_task(). The commenter replied that using asyncio has no use if the 'code has no concurrency'. I am unsure what this entails exactly, but I think it refers to the code not having methods such as gather() and create_task() .
So, for instance, by putting the await keyword in front of the connect_robust function, what other code is able to run while connect_robust would have to wait internally?
One guess I have is that the code inside the aio-pika library itself does use functions like gather() that do make this code run asynchronously, and thus requires the await word. But I cannot seem to find a definite answer that this could be the case.
This is the code that I played around with:
Asynchronous
import asyncio

async def count():
    print("One")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("Two")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(count(), count(), count())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

One
One
One
Two
Two
Two

Synchronous (what aio-pika's code looks like to me)
import asyncio

async def count():
    print("One")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("Two")

async def main():
    await count()
    await count()
    await count()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

One
Two
One
Two
One
Two


As it seems to me, the main thing in asyncio is not blocking IO calls, so gather and create_task just handle it, but await keyword gives you ability to execute coroutine in non blocking style also, so any other "event" that may happen will be executed until coroutine is awaited and GIL is not locked. I can see your misunderstanding of what happens here, let me try to clarify with code example:
consumer.py
import asyncio

import aio_pika
from aio_pika.abc import AbstractIncomingMessage


async def main() -> None:
    # here connection created, and it is not necessarily to be async
    # but as connection is IO operation, why not, cause could be some
    # suits where it is needed to be async.
    connection = await aio_pika.connect()
    async with connection:
        channel = await connection.channel()

        queue = await channel.declare_queue("hello")
        await queue.consume(on_message)
        await asyncio.Future()


async def on_message(message: AbstractIncomingMessage) -> None:
    print('Get message from callback')
    # non blocking sleep for 5 seconds, so there another messages could 
    # be handled during this time.
    await asyncio.sleep(5)  
    # async call to ack message
    await message.ack()
    print(f'Message body: {message.body}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

publisher.py
import asyncio

import aio_pika
from aio_pika import Message


async def main() -> None:
    connection = await aio_pika.connect()
async with connection:
    channel = await connection.channel()

    queue = await channel.declare_queue("hello")
    await channel.default_exchange.publish(
        Message(b"Hello World!"),
        routing_key=queue.name,
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Here if you run consumer.py and then run multiple times publisher.py you will see that consumer gets messages asyncrounously in non blocking style without using gather or exactly create_task but really task is creating under the hood, so you get what you expected from asyncio.
Maybe the main question is why we need to use async/await and async exactly cause function still executes as synchronous(if no io task there and there is just regular code and GIL is locked), that's True, but to call IO bound operation in asyncio(not blocking style) like connections, queries to db, web requests etc. you need to call it from coroutines(async functions), and yes it is possible to call it from regular functions, but its too much overhead in coding to do so.
